# Android Studio fragment crashed onimagebuttonclick and when initializing objects

Tags: android

> I would be grateful if you help, because I have been sitting for half a week on this problem. In general, I first created a regular layout and later added Navigation Dravel from the standard template. I was too lazy and just moved the layout by deleting the fragment. Later I did a lot of things, but in general here

The application crashes when I click on SFLCl this is the button ShowTurnList.

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.gallery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Constant;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.R;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.ShowTurnirs;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.Tournaments;

public class TournamentFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText TName, TAdres, TDate, TTime, Find;
    private FirebaseDatabase isDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference isRef = isDB.getReference("Tournaments");
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> listData;
    private List<Tournaments> listTemp;
    private ListView turnirs, findList;
    private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    private Button bFind, bCreate;



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tournament, container, false);
        //getDataFromDB(); //позже удалить нужно, не думаю что она должна находиться тут. Вместо этого шоутурниры
       // setOnClickItem();
        //turnirs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
        //init();
        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        init();
        turnirs =  getView().findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
    }

    //присвоение элементов к переменным
    private void init()//тут где то проблема нужно исправить 07.01
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Init", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*TName = TName.findViewById(R.id.edNameTournament);
        TAdres = TAdres.findViewById(R.id.edAdres);
        TDate = TDate.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirDate);
        TTime = TTime.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirTime);
        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        listTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        Find = Find.findViewById(R.id.edFindTournir);
        bFind = bFind.findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
        bCreate = bCreate.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);*/
    }

    //верхнее меню, замена табхосту
    public void STLCl(View view){
       /*bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      /*  findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getDataFromDB();*/

    }
    public void SCcl(View view){
        bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    public void SFcl(View view){
        bFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
//получение данных для первой вкладки Турниры
    private void getDataFromDB()
    {
        ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0){listData.clear();}
                if (listTemp.size() > 0){listTemp.clear();}
                for (DataSnapshot ss : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tournaments tournaments = ss.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                    assert tournaments != null;
                    listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                    listTemp.add(tournaments);
                }
               //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //turnirs.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        isRef.addValueEventListener(vListener);
    }
    //получение фильтрованных данных для поиска
    public void FindB(View view)
    {
        Query findQuery = isRef.child("Tournaments").orderByValue().equalTo(Find.getText().toString());
        findQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tournaments tournaments = ds.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                    assert tournaments != null;
                    listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                    listTemp.add(tournaments);
                    }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                findList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
//кнопка добавления записи в турниры
    public void btnCreateTournament(View view)
    {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(TAdres.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(TDate.getText().toString())){
            String id = isRef.getKey();
            String TourName = TName.getText().toString();
            String TAdress = TAdres.getText().toString();
            String ToDate = TDate.getText().toString();
            String ToTime = TTime.getText().toString();
            Tournaments newTrnir = new Tournaments(id, TourName, TAdress, ToDate, ToTime);
            isRef.push().setValue(newTrnir);
            if (newTrnir != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succecc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    //слушатель нажатий на "турнир"
    private void setOnClickItem()
    {
        turnirs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Tournaments tournaments = listTemp.get(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowTurnirs.class);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_NAME, tournaments.TournName);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_LINK, tournaments.TAdress);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_DATE, tournaments.ToDate);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_TIME, tournaments.ToTime);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
//слушатель ошибок, не работает нужно удалить
    public void onCancelled (ErrorManager errorManager){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorManager.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

and XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.TournamentFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edFindTournir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shFind"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="btnCreateTournament"
        android:text="Создать"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTrnirTime"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edAdres"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Место проведения"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edNameTournament"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/FindList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFind"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edTrnirDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Дата"
        android:inputType="date"
         android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edAdres"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edTrnirTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Время"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTrnirDate"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edNameTournament"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Название турнира"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shFind"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFind"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="FindB"
        android:text="Поиск"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edFindTournir"
        tools:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/TurnirList"
        android:layout_width="403dp"
        android:layout_height="644dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shFind"
        tools:visibility="gone">

    </ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ShowTurnList"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:onClick="STLCl"
        android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shCreate"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:onClick="SCcl"
        android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/shFind"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="192dp"
        android:onClick="SFcl"
        android:src="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sorry translated for the vocabulary in Google translator

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.gallery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Constant;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.R;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.ShowTurnirs;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.Tournaments;

public class TournamentFragment extends Fragment {
    /*private EditText TName, TAdres, TDate, TTime, Find;
    private FirebaseDatabase isDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference isRef = isDB.getReference("Tournaments");
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> listData;
    private List<Tournaments> listTemp;*/
    private ListView turnirs;
   // private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
    //private Button bFind, bCreate;



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /*galleryViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);*/
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tournament, container, false);
        //getDataFromDB(); //позже удалить нужно, не думаю что она должна находиться тут. Вместо этого шоутурниры
       // setOnClickItem();
        //turnirs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
        //init();
        return root;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //init();
        turnirs =  getView().findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
    }

    //присвоение элементов к переменным
  /*  private void init()//тут где то проблема нужно исправить 07.01
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Init", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*TName = TName.findViewById(R.id.edNameTournament);
        TAdres = TAdres.findViewById(R.id.edAdres);
        TDate = TDate.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirDate);
        TTime = TTime.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirTime);
        listData = new ArrayList<>();
        listTemp = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        Find = Find.findViewById(R.id.edFindTournir);
        bFind = bFind.findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
        bCreate = bCreate.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
    }*/

    //верхнее меню, замена табхосту
    public void STLCl(View view){
        try{ /*bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
            turnirs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           /* findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            getDataFromDB();*/
        }catch(Exception e){
            onPause();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace(); }

    }
   /* public void SCcl(View view){
        bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    public void SFcl(View view){
        bFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
//получение данных для первой вкладки Турниры
    private void getDataFromDB()
    {
        ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0){listData.clear();}
                if (listTemp.size() > 0){listTemp.clear();}
                for (DataSnapshot ss : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tournaments tournaments = ss.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                    assert tournaments != null;
                    listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                    listTemp.add(tournaments);
                }
               //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //turnirs.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
        isRef.addValueEventListener(vListener);
    }
    //получение фильтрованных данных для поиска
    public void FindB(View view)
    {
        Query findQuery = isRef.child("Tournaments").orderByValue().equalTo(Find.getText().toString());
        findQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tournaments tournaments = ds.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                    assert tournaments != null;
                    listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                    listTemp.add(tournaments);
                    }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                findList.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
//кнопка добавления записи в турниры
    public void btnCreateTournament(View view)
    {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(TAdres.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(TDate.getText().toString())){
            String id = isRef.getKey();
            String TourName = TName.getText().toString();
            String TAdress = TAdres.getText().toString();
            String ToDate = TDate.getText().toString();
            String ToTime = TTime.getText().toString();
            Tournaments newTrnir = new Tournaments(id, TourName, TAdress, ToDate, ToTime);
            isRef.push().setValue(newTrnir);
            if (newTrnir != null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succecc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    //слушатель нажатий на "турнир"
    private void setOnClickItem()
    {
        turnirs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Tournaments tournaments = listTemp.get(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowTurnirs.class);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_NAME, tournaments.TournName);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_LINK, tournaments.TAdress);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_DATE, tournaments.ToDate);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_TIME, tournaments.ToTime);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
//слушатель ошибок, не работает нужно удалить
    public void onCancelled (ErrorManager errorManager){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorManager.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}*/

}
```

I commented everything, all the code that I wrote except SFLCl, nothing helped. At the moment, it should just show the ListView turnirs, but the error still remains

Comment: P.S.translated in google translator

Comment: crashes when I press any button, sometimes it does not even enter

Comment: I would look at the logs, but the emulator does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Wrap your function statements in try catch. So that you can better get the exact exception/error.
try{
  /*bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
        turnirs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      /*  findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getDataFromDB();*/
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: Maybe there is an error in db function call.

Comment: @Wajahat Hussain but how can I display an error if I do not have access to logcat. I am currently testing the application by simply transferring the app-debug to my smartphone. I've tried onPause (); + toast, but the application just crashes as before

Comment: I commented everything, all the code that I wrote except SFLCl, nothing helped. At the moment it should just show the ListView turnirs, but no

Comment: by the way, ImageButton is used here and fragment maybe they have any peculiarities

Comment: You really need to look at the logcat.  If you can't connect the phone to your computer, can you use ADB over Wi-Fi?

Comment: @Ryan M, no, the computer is personal and does not have a wi-fi module. installed all sorts of universal adb servers, nothing helped. Intel haxm installed

Comment: this is a fragment from the navigation drawer template and it has a ViewModal maybe there is some other vocabulary ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by adding setOnClickListener

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.gallery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Constant;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.R;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.ShowTurnirs;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.Tournaments;

public class TournamentFragment extends Fragment {
    private FirebaseDatabase isDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference isRef = isDB.getReference("Tournaments");
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> listData;
    private List<Tournaments> listTemp;
    private ListView turnirs;



    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tournament, container, false);
        //getDataFromDB(); //позже удалить нужно, не думаю что она должна находиться тут. Вместо этого шоутурниры
        // setOnClickItem();
        //turnirs = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
        //init();
        EditText tName = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.edNameTournament);
        EditText tAdres = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.edAdres);
        EditText tDate = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirDate);
        EditText tTime = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.edTrnirTime);
        EditText Find = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.edFindTournir);
        Button bCreate = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);
        Button b2 = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.shCreate);
        Button bFind = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.btnFind);
        ListView turnirs = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.TurnirList);
        ListView findList = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.FindList);
        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.ShowTurnList);
        ImageButton b3 = (ImageButton) root.findViewById(R.id.shFind);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 {
                    bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bCreate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tAdres.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bFind.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                turnirs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                getDataFromDB();
                if (listData != null){turnirs.setAdapter(adapter);}
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bFind.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bCreate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Find.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tAdres.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                turnirs.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        //получение фильтрованных данных для поиска
        bFind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Query findQuery = isRef.child("Tournaments").orderByValue().equalTo(Find.getText().toString());
                findQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
                            Tournaments tournaments = ds.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                            assert tournaments != null;
                            listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                            listTemp.add(tournaments);
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        findList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //кнопка добавления записи в турниры
        bCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(tAdres.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(tDate.getText().toString())){
                    String id = isRef.getKey();
                    String TourName = tName.getText().toString();
                    String TAdress = tAdres.getText().toString();
                    String ToDate = tDate.getText().toString();
                    String ToTime = tTime.getText().toString();
                    Tournaments newTrnir = new Tournaments(id, TourName, TAdress, ToDate, ToTime);
                    isRef.push().setValue(newTrnir);
                    if (newTrnir != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

//получение данных для первой вкладки Турниры
    private void getDataFromDB()
    {
        ValueEventListener vListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (listData.size() > 0){listData.clear();}
                if (listTemp.size() > 0){listTemp.clear();}
                for (DataSnapshot ss : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Tournaments tournaments = ss.getValue(Tournaments.class);
                    assert tournaments != null;
                    listData.add(tournaments.TournName);
                    listTemp.add(tournaments);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        isRef.addValueEventListener(vListener);
    }
    

    //слушатель нажатий на "турнир"
    private void setOnClickItem()
    {
        turnirs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Tournaments tournaments = listTemp.get(position);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowTurnirs.class);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_NAME, tournaments.TournName);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_LINK, tournaments.TAdress);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_DATE, tournaments.ToDate);
                    i.putExtra(Constant.TOUR_TIME, tournaments.ToTime);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



}
```